# Add my personal repo to Ubuntu main repository(s)

Tags: apt, repository

I have a repository sitting in Launchpad (http://ppa.launchpad.net/symonmayn/vkey/ubuntu)
Can someone tell me how to add this to an Ubuntu global repository so it can be directly installed via sudo apt install  or by a gui package manager?
Otherwise nobody will know about my repo :-(
Is this even possible?
Any help would be muchly appreciated..
Sy.

Comment: I don't think that's possible...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add your PPAs to the main ubuntu repositories.  The only way to get them added for the system is to use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:symonmayn/vkey` and that will only work on Ubuntu systems.  And this has to be done person by person.

If you want to make your packages available in Ubuntu standard repositories, you need to start (typically) by making sure your package lands and is accepted into Debian. Or attempt to get your package added to Ubuntu directly.  Refer to https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html for the Ubuntu process.

Otherwise, the PPAs are all individually opt-in by administrators of endpoint systems, so those who want to use your repositories/softwrae can add your PPA themselves on their systems.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you so much for that.